# Carrierwave remote attachment url not working on creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have the following model called ApplicationAttachment in my Ruby on Rails project.

I also have uploaded files on my s3 bucket. When i try to upload the image to my model, i dont get an error but attachment is nil and the remote_attachment_url is not saving the file. Not sure what is the problem.

My code is this

```
ApplicationAttachment.create!(remote_attachment_url: "http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Plugin-For-Fullscreen-Image-Viewer-Chroma-Gallery.jpg")
```

This doesnt return any error but it doesnt save the image.

```
class ApplicationAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :attachment, DeveloperReferralAttachmentUploader
  attr_accessible :id, :attachment, :remote_attachment_url, :created_at, :updated_at
end

class DeveloperReferralAttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(pdf jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

How do i ensure that the remote_image_url saves when created via Carrierwave.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to explicitly save the attachment instead of using `create`.

```
aa = ApplicationAttachment.new(
       remote_attachment_url: "http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Plugin-For-Fullscreen-Image-Viewer-Chroma-Gallery.jpg"
     )
aa.save
```